# sum of series with square power

Tags: sequences-and-series

Is there an explicit expression to calculate the sum of a series with a square power?
\begin{equation}
\sum_{k= 1}^{N}{r ^{k^2}} \  or  \sum_{k= 1}^{\infty}{r ^{k^2}} \
\end{equation}
regards
arthur

Comment: It can be expressed in terms of *theta functions* (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).

Comment: thanks mjqxxxx - I'll study the Integral representations.

Comment: You may want to take a look at Jacobi Triple Product https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product